# некорректный перевод из hex в ascii

Tags: c, массивы, функции, hex, ascii

Доброго времени суток! Имеется следующий код:

```
int hex_to_int(char c) 
{
    int first = c / 16 - 3;
    int second = c % 16;
    int result = first * 10 + second;
    if (result > 9) result--;
    return result;
}
int hex_to_ascii(char c, char d)
{
    int high = hex_to_int(c) * 16;
    int low = hex_to_int(d);
    return high + low;
}
void main()
{
    char *ascii, *ascii_UP;
    char *str = "504B030414000600080000002100DFCC18F5C2010000460C0000130008025B436F6E74656E745F54797065735D2E786D6C20A2040228A0000200";
    int l = 0, length = strlen(str), ind = 0;
    char buf = 0;
    ascii = (char*)malloc(400 * sizeof(char));
    ascii_UP = (char*)malloc(400 * sizeof(char));
    memset(ascii, 0, 400 * sizeof(char));
    memset(ascii_UP, 0, 400 * sizeof(char));
    for (l = 0; l < length; l++) {
        if ( l % 2 != 0) {
            ascii[ind] = hex_to_ascii(buf, str[l]);
            printf("%c", hex_to_ascii(buf, str[l]));
            ind++;
        }
        else
            buf = str[l];
    }
```

в `str` хранится hex - вое представление первых нескольких байт документа .pptx. Необходимо перевести данное представление в ascii. Проблема в том, что если выводить на печать, то все выводится корректно. Но если после цикла выполнить команду `printf("%s ", ascii)`, то выведется лишь PK и две палочки. Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста, в чём проблема?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPDATE**

Благодаря ответу, данному к топику, переделал код в `main` следующим образом:

```
    ascii = (char*)malloc(400 * sizeof(char));
    ascii_UP = (char*)malloc(400 * sizeof(char));
    memset(ascii, 0, 400 * sizeof(char));
    memset(ascii_UP, 0, 400 * sizeof(char));
    substr = (char*)malloc(3 * sizeof(char));
    memset(substr, 0, 3 * sizeof(char));
    for (l = 0; l < length; l += 2) {
        strncpy(substr, str_TMP, 2);
        dbuf = strtol(substr, NULL, 16);
        str_TMP += 2;
        sprintf(ascii_UP, "%c", dbuf);
        strcat(ascii,ascii_UP);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`%s` подразумевает *строку* в стиле C. Для которой нуль - ее завершение.

Когда вы переводите строку в ascii, то шестым у вас идет что? Нулевой байт. На этом `printf` считает свою задачу выполненной...

Вот только ваш метод перевода в строку символов что-то представляется мне несколько усложненным (правильным или нет - тут я не копал, но раз вы говорите, что посимвольно все правильно - у меня нет оснований вам не доверять). Вы не думали воспользоваться функцией `strtol`, например?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Насчёт функции: да как-то особо не задумывался.. А разве она поможет решить проблему?

Comment: По крайней мере, с ней будет явно проще :)

Comment: только что переделал :) Спасибо за совет.

Comment: Ну, если ответ устроил - помечайте как принятый :)